# Solve the functional equation $f(ax)=\frac{1}{e^{a+b-x}+e^{bx}}h(x)+f(bx)$ for $f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-equations

Solve the functional equation $$f(ax)=\frac{1}{e^{a+b-x}+e^{bx}}h(x)+f(bx)$$ for $f(x)$ where $h(x)$ is a given function?

You can use any conditions on $f$ and $h$ (like continuity, differentiablity etc) as far as I get some 'nice' non-trivial solution.

Perhaps one of the ways is to exploit the Taylor series and compare the coefficients  which is not an efficient way.

Comment: What is the source of this question, if I may ask?

Comment: If $a=b$, there is no solution unless $h=0$.